# What are the client requirements for a .NET Outlook-AddIn (VSTO 2010)?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, requirements

we are planning to implement a Outlook-Addin (2007/2010). Our first attempt would be to do it with VSTO 2010, but we wonder if there are some special requirements on the client in this case.

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of thing you're thinking of/worried about?

Comment: Like .NET framework in a specific version or VSTO runtime components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO 2010 is required for Office 2010 but if you want to support both Office versions with one add-in you'll have to use version 12 of the PIAs and not 14.
What is required is:

- VSTO 2010
- PIAs 12
- .NET framework (4.0 gives you more VSTO stuff: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/04/23/why-should-i-upgrade-from-net-framework-3-5-to-net-framework-4.aspx)
- Outlook (you should really develop with 2007 on your machine and keep 2010 off of it)

Comment: Thank you RobertG5, but I think you are talking of the development machine. What I ment was the client on which i deploy the AddIn.

Comment: I was referring to either, actually. The redistributables for VSTO, PIA, and the .Net framework applies to client. The last bullet was to save you some headaches ;)

Comment: You shouldn't need the PIAs with .NET 4.0/VSTO 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

For clients, you build the installer (ClickOnce or SetupProject) which handles the required components (.NET 4.0, PIAs).

VSTO 2010 does the job of embedding the PIAs into the installer DLLs. VSTO for 2007 did not allow for this and always required the installation of the PIA (primary interop assemblies) which overwrote any existing PIA versions.

VSTO 2010 has many fixes for memory leaks and speed issues. VSTO 2010 is also backwards compatible with Office 2007.